Function that has parameters as pointers is not working when I take in addresses of variables
The code here is for filtering an image
        //variables for purpose of shortening some lines
        int b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        int g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        int r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;

        int bound = 255;

        //variables here are for rounding purposes
        float Sb = .272 * r + .534 * g + .131 * b;
        int tempSb = .272 * r + .534 * g + .131 * b;
        
        //rounding to nearest integer
        if (Sb != tempSb && Sb >= tempSb + 0.5)
        {
            tempSb++;
        }
        //checking if that rounded integer is higher than bound (and if so set it to bound)
        void nohigherthan_int(&bound, &tempSb);
        //setting the correct pixel to sepia blue
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempSb;


        void nohigherthan_int(int *a, int *b)
        {
            if (*a <= *b)
            {
                *b = *a;
            }
        }

and this code is for the function I am struggling with since the terminal is saying ,firstly
"expected parameter declarator" pointing to &bound (i.e the address for the bound variable)
and secondly that the prototype I have put doesn't match the function (aka it is saying a
function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of c, conflicting with a
previous declaration then pointing to my prototype and the function in which I put the variable
&bound, &tempSb
the function prototype is just a copy paste of the function I declared above (which I put above
the rest of the code)
I have tried to change the values to int *a = &bound and int *b = &tempSb and the errors did go away
but default arguments aren't supported.

void nohigherthan_int(&bound, &tempSb);

This line is a problem and more precisely void.  Remove void and it will compile OK
When you have void at the beginning the compiler treats it as declaration (and it has the wrong syntax in this case), not a function call.
Also, remember to have a function prototype before the first call.
void nohigherthan_int(int *a, int *b);


Ohhhh thanks a lot I thought there something wrong the adresses.

You should write you’re function before the code where you need it, or just write the function header like
void nohighertan_int(int *a, int *b);
 //now you wrote the header
 void youre_function(){
    int bound = value;
    int tempSB = other_value;
    nohighertan_int(&bound, &tempSB);
 }
void nohighertan_int(int *a, int *b){
   // function code here
}

The problem is with How the compiler generates the binary code for the function. It come’s from top to the bottom
